# "ERROR: Unable to load GDAL library" occurs when trying to GRASS functions in QGIS

Tags: gdal, grass-gis, error

I'm new to QGIS. I'm using GRASS operations to analyze raster layers and getting `ERROR: Unable to load GDAL library` in QGIS. Maybe the path is wrong which should point the GRASS operations to GDAL. Any tips?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to this forum. To start with, can you please add a bit more details of your problem by editing your original question? Like how did you installed QGIS and GRASS: as standalone or OSGeo4W installer and what OS you are in? Also a screen shot of the error you are receiving will help to identify what is going on. Please have a look at other questions to refer how screenshots and code snippets are provided with questions.

Answer (score 2):

thanks for your response! So, I just resolved it finally by searching for and deleting all traces of the previous install attempts. It was originally the "standalone" installer, 3.16 with Grass 7, version 2.0; Mac, Catalina 10.15.7.

After erasing/uninstalling everything I could find from previous install attempts; I again installed the newest package installer from qgis.org, and it is now working.

Before that, here was situation:

There was this error on startup:

**"2021-03-20T22:44:46     WARNING    GRASS
init error : Problem in GRASS initialization, GRASS provider and plugin will not work : Module built against version 2021-02-10T17:13:06+00:00 but trying to use version 2021-02-10T17:08:53+00:00. You need to rebuild GRASS GIS or untangle multiple installations.**

And then this error when trying to run various GRASS tools:

**"ERROR: Unable to load GDAL library"**

So I had tried many times to reinstall, and maybe somehow I hadn't successfully erased the older versions (even though I thought I had). As far as I know its not possible to manage or update Grass on its own, because its part of the program.

I hope this post will be helpful to future people like me! Sorry for the beginner-level questions and I appreciate the respone :-).